# Set default value in <s:checkbox> tag

Tags: checkbox, struts2, struts-tags

I am using `<s:checkbox>` of  Struts 2.3
the following is the line of code

```
<s:checkbox  theme="simple" name ="Mychkbox" value="R" onclick="Auto_Au('rej');"/>
```

Now in this I need this value in action , but I am not  finding any way to set this value `"R"` because
the `fieldValue` Parameter of  `<s:checkbox>` will give `true` or `false`.

I need to set the value as `'R'` that can be accessed in the action class.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using  private boolean Mychkbox; it give  result like true or false.make correct it boolean to String datatype.

your value must set in fieldValue="R"

action.jsp

```
    <s:form action="mylogin">
     <s:checkbox  theme="simple" name ="Mychkbox" fieldValue="R" value="true" onclick="Auto_Au('rej');"/>
     </s:form>
```

MyAction.class

```
    private String Mychkbox;
     public String execute() throws Exception {
          System.out.Println(" vaue : "+Mychkbox);
     }
```

value attributes-boolean type.(UI components value set)

fieldValue attribute--string type(value of Mychkbox)

Answer (score 0):

`<s:checkbox name="checkMe" fieldValue="true" label="Check Me for testing"/>` 
this is the syntax for Checkbox.By using same name(here name is 'checkMe') and adding getter and setter method for it in action class we can get this value in action class.
example:My Action.class

```
private String checkMe;

public String getCheckMe() {
        return checkMe;
    }
public void setCheckMe(String checkMe) {
        this.checkMe = checkMe;
    }
```

by using the getCheckMe() method we can get the value of checkbox 'checkMe'.

In your example use 'mychkbox' instead of 'checkMe'.
This site have a simple example/ [Struts 2 checkbox Checkbox Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You need a property in your target Action with the following setter

```
setMychkbox(String mychkbox){
    this.mychkbox = mychkbox;
}
```

but you are using a capital letter in your `name` attribute, that will prevent the correct mapping by Struts2.

Change it to

```
<s:checkbox theme="simple" name ="mychkbox" value="R" onclick="Auto_Au('rej');"/>
```

with a lowercase starting `m` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `checkbox` input field that is submitted by default is set to `true`. You can change this by providing `fieldValue` attribute of the `checkbox` tag. For example

```jsp
<s:checkbox  theme="simple" name ="mychkbox" fieldValue="R" onclick="Auto_Au('rej');"/>
```

If you want to preset the value of the input element you should provide a `value` attribute. For example

```jsp
<s:checkbox  theme="simple" name ="mychkbox" fieldValue="R" value="%{mychkbox}" onclick="Auto_Au('rej');"/>
```

Note that for better readability I've changed the name of the field. To map a field name to the action bean you should provide a property for the `mychkbox`.

```java
private String mychkbox;

public String getMychkbox() {
  return mychkbox;
}

public void setMychkbox(String mychkbox) {
  this.mychkbox= mychkbox;
}
```

The default stack of interceptors include [`checkbox` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/checkbox-interceptor.html) for which you should specify `uncheckedValue` parameter. For this purpose you should override the parameter of the interceptor

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="checkbox">
  <param name="uncheckedValue">undefined</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```